# Is the JVM able to do trivial recursive call precomputation?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, microbenchmark

A while ago, I ran rust benchmarks of two different software multiplication algorithms: trivial recursive multiplication and Russian peasant multiplication.

To my amazement the compiler was able to analyze the trivial recursion, replacing the call to the method directly with the result (e.g. calling `mul0(4,8) -> 32` ).

To see if the JVM is able to perform the same optimization, I measured the below Java implementation via JMH. Yet, the Russian peasant algorithm is faster and it seems that the VM is not performing any similar optimization.

Is there a similar optimization technique (replace recursive call with precomputed result) build into the JVM or is this something that the JVM does not do per se for some reason?

I am aware that this is VM dependent and might change, so I am more interested in general roadblocks that hinder VM implementators to incorporate such an optimization into their VM.

Code snippets:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 10)
@Fork(value = 2)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MyBenchmark {

    private int F1 = 542;
    private int F2 = 323;

    public final static int mul0(int a, int b) {
        if (a == 1) {
            return b;
        }
        return mul0(a - 1, b) + b;
    }

    //O(log n)
    public final static int mul2(int a, int b) {
        if (a == 1) {
            return b;
        }

        int sum = ((a & 1) == 1) ? b : 0;

        return mul2(a / 2, b + b) + sum;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void test0() {
        mul0(F1, F2);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void test2() {
        mul2(F1, F2);
    }

}
```

Results:

```
Result: 13852692,903 ▒(99.9%) 532102,125 ops/s [Average]
  Statistics: (min, avg, max) = (9899651,068, 13852692,903, 15356453,576), stdev = 945811,061
  Confidence interval (99.9%): [13320590,778, 14384795,028]


# Run complete. Total time: 00:02:22

Benchmark                   Mode  Samples         Score  Score error  Units
d.s.m.MyBenchmark.test0    thrpt       40   1453817,627    68528,256  ops/s
d.s.m.MyBenchmark.test2    thrpt       40  13852692,903   532102,125  ops/s
```

Comment: Depends on the JVM because it depends on the JIT compiler. What JVM are you interested in? It's possibly also platform-dependent.

Comment: Currently running a JDK8 64Bit on windows. But I am more interested why this is not already implemented asit looks like a relatively easy thing to do (but I have almost no experience in writing compilers).  Why can this be platform-dependent?

Comment: I'm measuring the exact same performance for both algorithms with JMH with Java 9.

Comment: @JornVernee cool will try that with JDK9 when time permits. I included my results in the question.

Comment: Ok, I was just testing with your `mul0(4,8) -> 32` example. Larger numbers are less trivial to inline. Afaik that would require better constant propagation, which is an ongoing project: [JEP309](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177279) and [JEP303](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178320) (and probably others)

Comment: I'm afraid, the number of useful optimizations is rather unlimited and this one doesn't belong to the most useful ones. If you cared about the speed, you could use `static final X = mul0(F1, F2)` so it gets computed just once. When you need such an expression, then there are chances that you need the general case, too and then you should wrap the computation in a caching method (this is something I use for a good deal of Project Euler problems). Here, the compiler can't help you as it can't choose the caching strategy for you - that's a different level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

HotSpot JVM is capable of such optimization, but the default JVM options prevent from doing this.

#### Long answer

First of all, the benchmark needs to be slightly corrected to see the effect.

1. By design, fields of `@State` classes are re-read on each iteration. JVM does not know they are constants, so it cannot constant-fold them. Make `F1` and `F2` final to make them constants and allow further optimization.
2. Benchmark methods should *consume* computation results either by calling `Blackhole.consume` or simply by returning a value from the method.

   ```
   private final int F1 = 542;
   private final int F2 = 323;

   public final static int mul0(int a, int b) {
       if (a == 1) {
           return b;
       }
       return mul0(a - 1, b) + b;
   }

   //O(log n)
   public final static int mul2(int a, int b) {
       if (a == 1) {
           return b;
       }

       int sum = ((a & 1) == 1) ? b : 0;

       return mul2(a / 2, b + b) + sum;
   }

   @Benchmark
   public int test0() {
       return mul0(F1, F2);
   }

   @Benchmark
   public int test2() {
       return mul2(F1, F2);
   }
   ```

Now HotSpot can inline method calls and perform constant folding. However, by default the inlining of recursive methods is limited just by one level. We can override this with the following options:

```
-XX:MaxInlineLevel=20 -XX:MaxRecursiveInlineLevel=20
```

Now `test2` becomes really fast, since it obviously performs less than 20 method calls:

```
Benchmark               Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.test0       avgt    5  675,763 ± 16,422  ns/op
MyBenchmark.test2       avgt    5    5,320 ±  0,274  ns/op
```

Looking into generated assembly code using `-prof perfasm` we may verify that `test2` returns the precomputed value:

```
0x00000000038e5960: mov    %r10,0x20(%rsp)
0x00000000038e5965: mov    0x58(%rsp),%rdx
0x00000000038e596a: mov    $0x2abda,%r8d        <<<<
0x00000000038e5970: data32 xchg %ax,%ax
0x00000000038e5973: callq  0x00000000037061a0  ;*invokevirtual consume
```

0x2abda = 175066 = 542 * 323 = mul2(F1, F2)

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze what that optimization means for the JVM.

**Is it possible?**

First, let's assume the JVM sees a call `mul0(4,8)` (of course, expressed in bytecode, but for the discussion, let's stay with the more readable Java source syntax). And let's assume this code block is executed often enough, so the HotSpot engine decides it's worth optimization.

Now the engine needs to see that in the `mul0()` method is a pure function, always returning the same result when called with the same arguments. That means traversing all instructions reachable from inside the mul0() method, and checking that they don't access anything variable besides the parameters.  I think the Hotspot engine is capable of similar reasoning, so this one should be doable as well.

Then the engine simply needs to run the recursive method one more time to find the result, and replace the `mul0(4,8)` call with loading an integer 32.

**Is it worth the pain?**

The reasoning I described only applies to fixed-argument situations as in `mul0(4,8)`. It doesn't work for variable `mul0(x,y)` calls.

You found out that the Java compiler already handles the constant-args case (at least sometimes), so doing it once more in the JVM isn't useful.

And the optimization will only help for programs that repeatedly do expensive computations with always the same args, over and over again. So it would only help developers that don't even know the basics of writing efficient code, and even worse, it won't educate them to improve their skills.

**Why is it useful in the Java compiler?**

If the compiler detects an expression to have a constant result, it can compute that result at compile-time, so even the first execution of the statement runs in "zero-time". So here it's investing a little bit of compile time to gain a better performance every time the program runs.